# How to change color?

Tags: javascript, html

i am using javascript ant html code for  current date display by default current date is displaying in black i want it in blue color how can i do this  please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body >

<p style="font-size:55px;background-color:#FFFF00">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
var now = new Date();
//var days = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
var months = new Array('01','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();
function fourdigits(number) {
return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
}
today = 
date + "-" +
months[now.getMonth()] + "-" +

(fourdigits(now.getYear())) ;
document.write(today);
// End -->
</script>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just adding it to the style?

```
<p style="font-size:55px;background-color:#FFFF00; color: blue">
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mJNB9/)

Answer (score 1):

You use the [CSS `color` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) in the same way that you are using the `background-color` property already.

Answer (score 0):

`color` determines the font color.

So you could do it inline:

`<p style="font-size:55px;background-color:#FFFF00;color:blue">`

or in a css:

`{
color: blue;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use .CSS file

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> // href is path to .css file
<head>

<body>
 <p id="data-color"> Your data() </p> // u can use id="anyName"

<body>
```

And in style.css file:

```
#data-color
{
 color: #000 // any color u want
}
```